# Sorting "year/month" string as descending dates

Tags: javascript, sorting, date

I have an array of objects, which contains "year/month" as a string value. I compare them as date objects, but the problem is that it fails if I am comparing year and the first month, as it is in the code: "2015" and "2015/1"

```js
const sortYearsMonthsDescending = (items) => items.sort((a, b) => (new Date(a.value) - new Date(b.value)));

const toBeSortedWorking = [{value: "2015"}, {value:"2015/3"}, {value: "2015/10"}];
const toBeSortedNotWorking = [{value: "1933"}, {value:"1933/11"}, {value: "1933/1"}];
console.log(sortYearsMonthsDescending(toBeSortedWorking));
console.log(sortYearsMonthsDescending(toBeSortedNotWorking));
```

Comment: and what should the just the year be when sorted?

Comment: The year should come always the very first, like this: [{value: "1932"}, {value:"1933/1"}, {value: "1932/11"}];

Comment: so add a check to see if it does not have a '/' and push it to the top

Comment: thanks, yes that would be the one way, but I will see if is possible to instantiate the dates such a way to avoid checking whether its only year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get the strings in a format that is easily comparable, either as strings or dates. However, using Dates gives an added issue of how to ensure 1933 is correctly sorted between 1932/12 and 1933/1.

The following sorts as strings by appending "/00" to any value that is only a year, and adding a leading zero to single digit months so "2015/3" is compared as "2015/03".

```js
var values  = [{value: "2015"}, {value:"2015/3"}, {value: "2015/10"}, {value: "1933"}, {value: "1932/12"}, {value:"1933/11"}, {value: "1933/1"}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(values));

values.sort(function(a, b) {
  function fixMonth(date) {
    var t = date.split('/');
    return t[0] + '/' + ('0'+t[1]).slice(-2); 
  }
  a = /\//.test(a.value)? fixMonth(a.value) : a.value + '/00';
  b = /\//.test(b.value)? fixMonth(b.value) : b.value + '/00';
  return a.localeCompare(b);
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
```

If a descending sort is required, just reverse the result.

Another version is:

```js
var values  = [{value: "2015"}, {value:"2015/3"}, {value: "2015/10"}, {value: "1933"}, {value: "1932/12"}, {value:"1933/11"}, {value: "1933/1"}];

values.sort(function(a, b) {
  a = /\//.test(a.value) ? a.value.replace(/(\/)(\d)$/, "$10$2") : a.value + '/00';
  b = /\//.test(b.value) ? b.value.replace(/(\/)(\d)$/, "$10$2") : b.value + '/00';
  return a.localeCompare(b);
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
```

Or even:

```js
var values  = [{value: "2015"}, {value:"2015/3"}, {value: "2015/10"}, {value: "1933"}, {value: "1932/12"}, {value:"1933/11"}, {value: "1933/1"}];

values.sort(function(a, b) {
  function resolve(s) {
    return /\//.test(s) ? s.replace(/(\/)(\d)$/, "$10$2") : s + '/00';
  }
  return resolve(a.value).localeCompare(resolve(b.value));
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let dates = ['2012','2018/1','2018','2014/3','2015','2012/5','2019','2013/7','2011/3','2010/10','2039/3'];

function compareDates(date1, date2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(date1.length, date2.length); i++) {
    if (date1[i] > date2[i]) return 1;
    else if (date1[i] < date2[i]) return -1;
    else if (!date1[i] && date2[i]) return -1;
    else if (date1[i] && !date2[i]) return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

console.log(dates.sort(compareDates));
```

Comment: This does not correctly sort single and double digit months, e.g. 2010/10 and 2010/2. You need to pad single digit months with a leading zero to get them to sort correctly as strings.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Fixing it wouldn't be difficult, but it would make it a bit messier, and I think there are enough solutions posted that work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it because `Date` is a `comparable object`
[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript#493018)

```js
const a = [{value: "2015"}, {value:"2015/3"}, {value: "2015/10"}];
const b = [{value: "1932"}, {value:"1933/11"}, {value: "1932/1"}];

function sort(items) {
  
  return items
    .sort((a, b) => {
      a = a.value.split('/');
      b = b.value.split('/');
      
      // months at Index = 1, consider as 0 based
      a[1] = a[1] ? (a[1] - 1) : 0;
      b[1] = b[1] ? (b[1] - 1) : 0;
      
      /* ASC */ return (new Date(...a)) - (new Date(...b)); 
      /* DESC */ return (new Date(...b)) - (new Date(...a)); 
    })
  ;
}

console.log('a = ', sort(a));
console.log('b = ', sort(b));
```

Comment: Re-indexing the months isn't necessary as they will sort correctly without it. The dates will be a month out, but it doesn't matter as they aren't used for anything else. This will treat "1933" and "1933/1" both as `new Date(1933,0)` so sorting may not be stable or correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to initialize the date in a way that distinguishes between having provided a value for the month or not since it uses default values for all in order to be able to create a valid date.

In this particular use-case I think you can add a secondary calculation on the length of the date strings, like this:

```
const sortYearsMonthsDescending = (items) => items.sort((a, b) => 
  (new Date(a.value) - new Date(b.value))) || (a.value.length - b.value.length);
```

Basically, this is an edge case where there's an ambiguity between `"2015"` and `"2015/1"`. We resolve this ambiguity with the statement "take the shorter string before the longer string".

Comment: You shouldn't use `new Date(a.value)` since parsing of a string like "2010/11" is entirely implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Note that bellow I included also the day for extensibility purposes. If not needed at all then can be easily removed.

**Solution 1 - string sorting key `YYYY-MM-DD-LLLLL`**

The following solution creates a key for sorting without using the `Date` object and considers also that a string without month or day should be treated first in an ascending sorting order.

The sorting key is: `YYYY-MM-DD-LLLLL` where `L` is length.

```js
  const ensureDigits = (value, digits) => {
    return (Math.pow(10, digits) + value).toString().slice(- digits);
  };
  
  const sortDateStrings = (dateStrLst, descending) => {
    
    return dateStrLst
      .map(dateStr => {
        const parts = dateStr.value.split('/');
        const year = parts[0];
        const month = ensureDigits(parts[1] || 1, 2);
        const day = ensureDigits(parts[2] || 1, 2);
        const length = ensureDigits(dateStr.value.length, 5);
        return { item: dateStr, sortKey: `${year}-${month}-${day}-${length}` }
      })
      .sort((model1, model2) => 
        model1.sortKey.localeCompare(model2.sortKey) * (descending ? -1 : 1))
      .map(model => model.item);
  }
  
  const dateStrLst1 = [{value: "2015"}, {value:"2015/3"}, {value: "2015/10"}];
  const dateStrLst2 = [{value: "1932"}, {value:"1933/11"}, {value: "1932/1"}];
  
  console.log(sortDateStrings(dateStrLst1).map(item => item.value));
  console.log(sortDateStrings(dateStrLst2).map(item => item.value));
  
  console.log(sortDateStrings(dateStrLst1, true).map(item => item.value));
  console.log(sortDateStrings(dateStrLst2, true).map(item => item.value));
```

**Solution 2 - order by date, then by length, using Lodash**

```js
  const sortDateStrings = (dateStrLst, descending) => {
    
    const model = dateStrLst
      .map(dateStr => {
        const parts = dateStr.value.split('/');
        const year = parts[0];
        const month = (parts[1] - 1) || 0;
        const day = parts[2] || 1;
        return { item: dateStr, date: new Date(year, month, day), length: dateStr.value.length };
      });
      
      const direction = descending ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    
    return _.orderBy(model, ["date", "length"], [direction, direction])
      .map(modelItem => modelItem.item);
  };
  
  const dateStrLst1 = [{value: "2015"}, {value:"2015/3"}, {value: "2015/10"}];
  const dateStrLst2 = [{value: "1932"}, {value:"1933/11"}, {value: "1932/1"}];
  
  console.log(sortDateStrings(dateStrLst1).map(item => item.value));
  console.log(sortDateStrings(dateStrLst2).map(item => item.value));
  
  console.log(sortDateStrings(dateStrLst1, true).map(item => item.value));
  console.log(sortDateStrings(dateStrLst2, true).map(item => item.value));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.2/lodash.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**WARNING: parsing date**

```
// valid ISO 8601 string
const date1 = new Date(Date.parse('1932'));
Fri Jan 01 1932 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)

// not a valid string
const date2 = new Date(Date.parse('1932/1'));
Fri Jan 01 1932 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)

// not a valid string
const date3 = new Date(Date.parse('1932/01'));
Fri Jan 01 1932 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)

date1.getTime() == date2.getTime();
false
```

also the same happens with:

```
// not a valid ISO 8601 string
const date2 = new Date(Date.parse('1932-1'));
Fri Jan 01 1932 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
```

but this one is correct:

```
// valid ISO 8601 string
const date3 = new Date(Date.parse('1932-01'));
Fri Jan 01 1932 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
```

and the same problem happens also with:

```
// incorrect usage of constructor
new Date(1932);
Thu Jan 01 1970 02:00:01 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)

// correct usage of constructor
new Date(1932, 0);
Fri Jan 01 1932 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
```

But this last one `new Date(1932)` is incorrect as the constructor allows at least year + month as in `new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);`.

Note that before I used `new Date(Date.parse(...))` because:

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

`Date` can parse:

> A string representing an [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) or [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).

In respect to this question, [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) formats are (notice that days and months are two digits only):

```
   Year:
      YYYY (eg 1997)
   Year and month:
      YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
   Complete date:
      YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
```

In respect to this question, [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) formats are:

```
date-time       =       [ day-of-week "," ] date FWS time [CFWS]
date            =       day month year
```

Therefore I find no format to match something similar to `1932/1` in order to parse consistently across browsers.

Performance wise might be to stick with `ISO 8601` format as is usually the first one being checked, then the `RFC2822`.

If you are using **momentjs** ensure that the format you are about to parse is supported by checking [parsing strings section](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).

**Conclusion:**

Create date objects consistently in order to obtain correct results:

- **Date constructor:** (gives local date) - `new Date(1932, 0)`
- **Date.parse()** (gives UTC date when used with ISO 8601 date only) - `Date.parse('1932')` same as `Date.parse('1932-01')` - notice the two digits for month

`Date.parse(<ISO_8601_string>)` gives UTC date (when date only) because:

> Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

Comment: I guess what you're saying is that '1932' will be parsed as UTC but '1932/1' as local. But  '1932/1' may not be parsed as a valid date string at all. :-(

Comment: @RobG I updated my answer to include also aspects regarding parsing. `1932/1` is indeed not a valid format which can work across browsers.